# How to replace elements of a list with elements of another list of a different size in python in the same index position without a loop

Tags: python, list

I want to use python to do the following. Let's say I have two list of lists:

```
list1 = [[0,0,0], 
         [0,0,0], 
         [0,0,0]]

list2 = [[ 1, "b"], 
         ["a", 4 ]]
```

And I want to replace the elements of `list1` with the elements of `list2` at the corresponding index value such that the output is:

```
output = [[  1,"b", 0], 
          ["a",  4, 0], 
          [  0,  0, 0]]
```

Is there a quick way of doing this instead of using a loop? Computational time is key for what I need this for. Please note I do not have access to pandas. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think using for loop will slower than using other function?

Comment: You could use the [Executor.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#executor-objects) on each lines to get a speed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `for` to go through each of the nested lists in turn - however this isn't really a loop - just processing them one after another.

For each inner list, you can use the following to always pick the elements in the second list if they exist/are true. `zip_longest` will pad the shorter list - by default it pads with `None` but for the first use we replace the 'gap' with an empty list so that the second `zip_longest` call can iterate over it:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list1 = [[0,0,0],
         [0,0,0],
         [0,0,0]]

list2 = [[ 1, "b"],
         ["a", 4 ]]


new_list = []
for l1, l2 in zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=[]):
    new_list.append([y if y else x for x, y in zip_longest(l1, l2)])
print(new_list)
```

Comment: `itertools` continues to amaze me with functionality. +1